# Is it possible to make a fully automatic installation of raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, boot, linux

My problem is : I want actually to make the sd card bootable directly to raspbian and when booting from it for the first time I don't need to select configuration options. I searched a lot but I am not sure if it can be made on raspberry pi.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst I got that from https://github.com/aaronmelton/AutomatedRaspbianInstaller after doing a search for "raspbian preseed"

Comment: I come across this tiny project. The problem with the perseeding that there is a bug with some commands for generating a perseeding file. I can confirm that on raspbian !

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are asking.

If your intention is to provide SD cards to others so they don't need to do any configuration then:

1. boot and configure one system as you desire
2. copy the SD card image to a computer
3. buy SD cards of the same size
4. copy the saved SD card image to each SD card
5. send out the SD cards

Comment: actually when installing any linux distributuion you need to provide some configuration options like keyboard layout language and to answer some question. For that you need to stay close to the laptop in order to provide the desired configuration. 
Now my case is to try to delete any kind of human interaction with the machine during installation of the operating system...I think it is much more clear now. I am still struggling to find a solution  that works with Raspbian !

Comment: Actually you don't need to provide keyboard and language.  The system will install quite happily without that information.  If you have your own constraints it would be sensible to edit them into your post.

Comment: I take those as an example but if you installed raspbian you will be sure that we need to select some configuration option.

Comment: do you have any idea about how to create a condigured os image ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the GUI, but if you use just SSH you don't need the first configuration, because SSH is activated by default. (I'm using the RaspPi this way because I haven't a screen). If your problem is the screen, you can install a VNC server via SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to leave the rpi install itself automatically without human interaction !

Comment: So you want to install directly Raspbian without NOOB and without also the first configuration utility?

Comment: exaclty...it will be preconfigured !I found that it need a preseeding configuration file !